# Batch Script.Bulk MKV videos metadata removal. OS X Mac

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks, matroska

When I run the below batch file that is using mkvpropedit and remove all tags and title from all mkv files within a directory.

I get the error:

***.mkv  Error: The file '*.mkv' is not a Matroska file or it could not be found.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.mkv
do
 echo -n $f  ' '
 /Applications/MKVToolNix-8.2.0.app/Contents/MacOS/mkvpropedit --tags all: --delete title "${f}"
done
```

The script is in the folder with the MKV files, in an external hard disk.

Is there something I am missing or using incorrect?.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you sure that the script is run from the directory where the mkv files are? Perhaps you could write `for f in /Volumes/ExternalDisk/path/to/files/*.mkv`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes, with your suggestion that giving the full path,  the script works.

But I am planning to run the script in many different folders of different external hard disks. It will mean that I have to edit the script for every folder.

What would be the cause that the original script is not working as it is?

Comment: Your issue seems to be that the script is run from another directory than you think. Best would be to get the directory of where the script resides and append that to the `*.mkv` in your for loop such that always the full path is used. [This might be helpful](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/bash-script-directory/). I don't have time now to put that in answer.